# Can I hide a grid row without applying styles to each row element?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to hide a row in a grid. I could do it by setting the `display` property for each cell in the row, but it doesn't seem very optimal. Is there a way to apply a style that targets an entire grid row as I've created it?

Comment: No, CSS-Grid rows are not elements and so cannot be selected with CSS,

Comment: @TylerH Nice rephrasing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grid is just a layout scheme.  With it, you cannot control the visibility of elements.  If you want to hide an element, you need to do this through display property.